# extend non ES6 object

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Working to understand the new ES6 syntax. If I have a class like the [Outlayer](https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer) library that is not written in ES6 but want to extend it with an ES6 class how would that look? The key extension point is [_getItemLayoutPosition](https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer/blob/master/outlayer.js#L337)

I tried something like this.

```
export let MyGrid = Outlayer.create('AnyGrid', {});

MyGrid._getItemLayoutPosition = function() {
   // this does not get called
}
```

If I do `new MyGrid(element)`

My extended _getItemLayoutPosition never gets called.

So then I thought maybe I need to extend the class

```
export class AnyGrid extends Outlayer {
  _getItemLayoutPosition(item) {
    return {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }
  }
}
```

This gives an error `Type 'typeof 'Outlayer'' is not a constructor function type.`

What is the proper way to extend this class so that I can override the `_getItemLayoutPosition` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Outlayer.create` actually creates a function that inherits from `Outlayer` you have to add the method on the prototype instead of the function itself

```
export let MyGrid = Outlayer.create('AnyGrid', {});

MyGrid.prototype._getItemLayoutPosition = function() {
   // this does not get called
}
```

Note that the function returned when you call `Outlayer.create` [has additional properties](https://github.com/metafizzy/outlayer/blob/master/outlayer.js#L867-L894) i.e. is not the same as creating a class that inherits from `Outlayer`

Comment: argh i thought I tried that as well but prototype was not defined!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
// AnyGrid- subclass
function AnyGrid() { 
    Outlayer.apply(this, arguments); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
AnyGrid.prototype = Object.create(Outlayer.prototype);
AnyGrid.prototype.constructor = AnyGrid;

//Add/Override the method
AnyGrid.prototype._getItemLayoutPosition = function() {
   // this does not get called
}
```

Don't forget to export `AnyGrid`.

Comment: This gives a couple errors ```Property 'prototype' does not exist on type 'typeof 'Outlayer''.``` and ```Property 'apply' does not exist on type 'typeof 'Outlayer'```'. Then there is something wrong with the export ```Declaration or statement expected.```

Comment: Ary you using the browser ?

Comment: oh Outlayer is available fine with ```import * as Outlayer from "Outlayer";```

Comment: Problem solved ? I don't have a clear idea about your environment  So my answer it's a little bit general !